# How to get hospital details with specialization using google map for android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I have created my application with Google Maps API for hospitals. I am able to get the nearest hospitals and displayed it. In Google maps it returns only details of the hospitals. But I need to get hospitals details with specializations like eye hospitals, diabetic center etc. I searched so far. But i cant get it. My question is google provides such options? Otherwise is there any API available to do like these kind of things? Can anybody clarify me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Maps API Does'nt provide such type of filter for hospitals near any particular location.So using Google Maps API it can'nt possible to get hospitals for specializations.

Check This is a simple Google Maps Hospital API [URL](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?types=hospital&location=37.787930,-122.4074990&radius=5000&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyBRuQwOy4jhyc3Xq8mrVEBZgK32bXdeIx8)

Thanks